# Получить адрес точки маршрута без дополнительного обращения к геокодеру?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в примере из песочницы можно включить режим редактирования и перетаскивать путевые точки маршрута. Есть ли возможность получить адрес после перетаскивания конкретной точки без дополнительного обращения к геокодеру?
[Пример из песочницы](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_edit)

Answer (score 1):

При перетаскивании точки маршрута по-умолчанию не делается запрос к геокодеру. Для того чтобы после перетаскивания происходил запрос к геокодеру, нужно использовать параметр reverseGeocoding.

```
multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
    referencePoints: [startPoint, finishPoint],
    params: {
        reverseGeocoding: true
    }
});
```

В этом случае новая точка хранит в себе адрес и Object-метаданные Геокодера. О них можно почитать тут:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1-dev/ref/reference/multiRouter.WayPoint-docpage/#field_detail__properties

К примеру получить адрес можно так:

```
multiRoute.getWayPoints().get(0).properties.get('address')
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/j6ykvsm7/1/

Comment: Не работает, вот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/4no8dvu0/

Comment: Забыл, что параметр reverseGeocoding по умолчанию выключен, вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/j6ykvsm7/1/

Comment: А еще подскажите, пожалуйста, а если добавлена только одна точка путевая, то вылезает ошибка, так как маршрута же нет? Можно, конечно сделать проверку на наличие маршрута, но хотел спросить. Если добавлена одна точка это уже не маршрут а что? Как получить доступ к ней и к ее адресу? Это вроде даже и  не placemark.

Comment: У меня не возникает ошибка тут к примеру https://jsfiddle.net/1ayxft45/